# jQuery Target Certain Number Of Elements From N

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

With jQuery I'm trying to select a certain number of elements from a collection of elements.  I only want to select and modify the number of elements that I define.  So in my code below I have a bunch of li's with the hidden class.  I'd like to only remove the hidden class from the first 5 elements.  I'll post my code below, it should make sense.  As of now I'm using a loop to go through the first 5.  Let me know if there's room for improvement.  Thanks!

```
('a.moreLink').live('click', function() {
    var $ul = $(this).parent().prev();
    var $li = $ul.children('li.hidden').first();
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        $li.removeClass('hidden');
        $li = $li.next('li');
    }
    if($ul.children("li.hidden").size() == 0) {
        $(this).text('Go to the full site to see more').attr('href', '#');
    }
});

<ul id="EventsList">
    <li></li>
    ....(4 more non hidden)
    <li class='hidden></li>
    ....(N more hidden)
</ul>
<div>
    <a href='#' id='MoreEvents' class='moreLink'>More Events</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `slice()`, `:lt()`, `:gt()` etc.., they all do this kind of thing, and it's all very well documented on the jQuery website?

Comment: `$('a.moreLink.hidden:lt(5)').removeClass('hidden')` (or some facsimile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.moreLink', function() {
    var $ul = $(this).parent().prev();
        $ul.children('li.hidden').slice(0,5).removeClass('hidden');

    if ($ul.children("li.hidden").length) {
        $(this).text('Go to the full site to see more').attr('href', '#');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like...

```
var count = 0;
$('li.hidden').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    count++;
    if(count >= 5)
        return false; //this breaks out of the .each()
});
```